# Can I repair a half construct?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, healing

I would like to know whether repair would heal a half construct.
Or is repair exclusive to whole constructs?

Answer (score 3):

**No**

Unlike for [Constructs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Construct) there is no rule to say that [half-constructs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/creating-new-races#subtype-half-construct) can be repaired or that they cannot be healed normally. If there was such a rule, you'd expect to find it under their list of features:

> A half-construct race has the following features:
>
> Half-constructs gain a +2 racial bonus on saving throws against
>   disease, mind-affecting effects, poison, and effects that cause either
>   exhaustion or fatigue.
>
> Half-constructs cannot be raised or resurrected.
>
> Half-constructs do not breathe, eat, or sleep, unless
>   they want to gain some beneficial effect from one of these activities.
>   This means that a half-construct can drink potions to benefit from
>   their effects and can sleep in order to regain spells, but neither of
>   these activities is required for the construct to survive or stay in
>   good health.

Note that they still cannot be raised or resurrected however.

Answer (score 2):

#### A half-construct is not a construct, and cannot be affected by things that only work on constructs.

From the PFSRD on [special subtypes for custom races](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/creating-new-races#subtype-half-construct):

> These subtypes can be added to any of the race types except for construct and undead. When you apply these subtypes to the humanoid type, choose another subtype as the creature's other half. For example, you could make a creature that is humanoid (half-construct, human).

A humanoid half-construct is a humanoid with the half-construct subtype; it does not have the construct type and cannot be treated as a construct.